# Eclipse error exit code=13, fix not working

Tags: java, eclipse

I had updated my Java version from version 6 to 8. Yesterday, and eclipse won't open I got error 13, googled the solution and applied the changes but its still not working. To confirm what is in my config file

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.100.v20150511-1540.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_64_1.1.300.v20150602- 1417
-product
org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256M
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256m
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.appendVmargs

-vm
C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_101\bin\javaw.exe
-vmargs

-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.7
-Xms256m
-Xmx1024m
```

Comment: Have you tried enclosing the -vm parameter in quotes ?

Comment: you mean by doing "-vm" ? @RamachandranGA

Comment: Something like this -vm "C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_101\bin\javaw.exe"

Comment: Try omitting the -vm argument - you only need this if you for some reason do not like the default jvm for Eclipse itself.  You can then tell Eclipse when it is running which JRE to use for your project.

Comment: when I do that it tells me that a jre or a jdk must be availiable in order to run eclipse error. @RamachandranGA

Comment: You are trying to run a 64-bit copy of Eclipse with a 32-bit Java Runtime. That will not work. They **must** match. https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/198527/

Comment: Install the 64 bit Java Runtime Environment giving you the "java" command directly from the command line

Comment: I have a 64 bit computer so and the eclipse file reads 32 even when I download 64 bit version from eclipse.org @nitind

Comment: You must understand why your system does what it does.  Delete your current eclipse folder and unzip it again.  Install 64-bit JRE.  Start Eclipse.

Comment: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jre8-downloads-2133155.html   I installed the Windows x64 offline version. that is what I have installed. My eclipse is a 64 bit version       C:\Users\admin\Downloads\eclipse-java-mars-2-win32-x86_64              @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen

Comment: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jre8-downloads-2133155.html offers JRE downloads. You're pointing the eclipse.ini at a 32-bit JDK. Look under the non-x86 "Program Files" directory for your installed 64-bit JRE.

Comment: thank you so much @nitind !!! I haven't been able to work for 2 days because of this. It worked thanks so much

Comment: nice glad this works.

Answer (score -1):

[image]

maybe you should clean the VM arguments and I saw you add a parameter 'Dosgi' it need jdk version 1.7 so maybe you should change your JDK version .

you can change your vm argements in debug configurations.

Comment: The problem is that @黄伟杰 I can't open eclipse

Comment: maybe you can change your JDK version to 1.7?

Comment: This is later. The problem is starting eclipse with a compatible Jvm

Comment: you konw the problem is JVM so you should change your JDK version ,because JDK means Java Development Kit it had cantain JVM in it .After you change your jdk to suitable version ,the jvm works too